# how to find file in subfolder's

Tags: python

how to get the file path
I have a directory

```
C: / User / Production
```

It has several folders (10), which also have subfolders.
I need to find the test.pdf file in one of the folders.

now my code can find the file only in the folders that are registered in folders.

My code

```
root = 'C:\\User\\Production'
folders = ['ONE','TWO','FREE','FOUR',......]
file = 'test.img'
folders_comtains_file = []
for folder in folders:
     filepath = path.join(root,folder,file)
     if path.isfile(filepath):
         folders_comtains_file.append(filepath)

print(orderName)
```

Comment: ```import os 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "C:\\Projects" # Your path
search_file = "aidan.ovpn" # File to search for

files_found = []

for path in [x[0] for x in os.walk(path)]:
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    files_found.append(path) if search_file in onlyfiles else []
 
print(files_found) # List of paths where file is found```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the os.walk method, it should help you find all the files in the sub directories https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm